# Sorting through an array and printing occurrences?

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, mips

I've never seen MIPS before and am trying to learn it for a project. Part of the project involves sorting through an array and printing how many times a specific letter appears.

For instance, if the word is "applestoapples", the number of times "a" appears is 2.

I'm not asking for code, I'm just asking for a general outline as to how I would start writing this code or a certain outline I can follow because I am drawing so many blanks.

Thank you

Comment: How would you write it in some other programming language that you know? Once you've done that, it should be clear to you _what_ the program needs to do and you can focus on _how_ to do that in MIPS assembly. If you've never programmed in MIPS assembly (or any kind of assembly language) before, maybe you should start with something a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same approach as with any other programming language.
One useful hint I can give you would be to write a subroutine that is used only for checking the similarity of 2 bytes (here each letter is 1 byte as you would expect same as in c++ or whatever HLL) and make it accept as argument 2 bytes in a0 and a1 and return v0=1 if same v0=0 if different.
Then in your main routine take the word and manipulate it as you need to.

You should probably ask more specific questions if possible we'll be glad to help